# Parameters are set to null while passing from Ajax to ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I am facing a problem posting data using Ajax to an ASP.NET Core controller.

I have an entity with this structure :

```
public class ProprieteBienFinance
{
    public int ProprieteBienFinanceId { get; set; }
    public string Libelle { get; set; }
    public int Rang { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChoixPropriete> Modalites { get; set; }
    public TypePropriete TypePropriete { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MetaBlocageAffichagePropriete> BlocageAffichagePropriete { get; set; }
    public string? Dependance { get; set; }

    public ProprieteBienFinance()
    {
        this.Modalites = new List<ChoixPropriete>();
        this.BlocageAffichagePropriete = new List<MetaBlocageAffichagePropriete>();
    }
}
```

and a "cshtml" page showing a list of this entity. I have set a Listener on this list to manage removing and adding members.

```
var proprietes = {};
var financement = {
    aInternal: proprietes,
    aListener: function (val) { },
    set a(val) {
        this.aInternal = val;
        this.aListener(val);
    },
    get a() {
        return this.aInternal;
    },
    registerListener: function (listener) {
        this.aListener = listener;
    }
}

financement.registerListener(function (val) {

    var dataToSend = {};
    dataToSend.caracteristiques = proprietes;
    $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: window.location.origin + "/ParametrageBiensFinanciers/AfficherCaracteristiquesFinancement",

                type: "post",

                dataType: "json",

                beforeSend: function (x) {
                    if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                        x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                    };
                    x.setRequestHeader('RequestVerificationToken', document.getElementById('RequestVerificationToken').value);
                },

                data: dataToSend,

                complete: function (result) {
                    // this code is to update the list printed and updated a hidden input
                    $("#displayProperties").html(result.responseText);
                    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
                    if (typeof (proprietes) != "undefined")
                        $("#nombreProprietesData").val(proprietes.length);
                    $("#displayProperties").show();

                }
            }
        );
});
```

The click on the update link is supposed to call a method on the controller and bring the form for update

```
<a title="Mettre à jour le type de financement" class="btn btn-primary btn-link btn-sm Edit" onclick="LoadUpdateForm(@counter)">
    <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
</a>

function LoadUpdateForm(rowNumber) {
    //les proprietes de base sont le libelle et le type 
    var idLibelleChamps = "#libelle_prop_" + rowNumber;
    var libelle = $(idLibelleChamps).html();

    var caracteristique = {};
    caracteristique = proprietes.find(element => element.rang == rowNumber);

    var dataToSend = {};
    dataToSend.caracteristiqueToUpdate = caracteristique;
    dataToSend.caracteristiques = proprietes;


    debugger;
    $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: window.location.origin + "/ParametrageBiensFinanciers/AfficherFormulaireModifCaracteristique",

                type: "post",

                dataType: "json",

                beforeSend: function (x) {
                    if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                        x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                    };
                    x.setRequestHeader('RequestVerificationToken', document.getElementById('RequestVerificationToken').value);
                },

                data: dataToSend,

                complete: function (result) {

                    $("#AjouterCaracteristiques").html(result.responseText);
                    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
                    $("TypePropriete").change(function () {
                        targetType($(this));
                    });
                    var extendedProperty = $("#selectExtendId option:selected");
                    if ((typeof ($(extendedProperty)) != "undefined") && $(extendedProperty).text() != "Choisir la caractéristique dépendante") {
                        var dataToSend = {};

                        dataToSend.libelle = $(extendedProperty).text();
                        dataToSend.caracteristiques = proprietes;
                        dataToSend.caracteristiqueToUpdate = caracteristique;
                        $.ajax
                            (
                                {
                                    url: window.location.origin + "/ParametrageBiensFinanciers/EtendreUneCaracteristique",

                                    type: "post",

                                    dataType: "json",

                                    beforeSend: function (x) {
                                        if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                                            x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                                        };
                                        x.setRequestHeader('RequestVerificationToken', document.getElementById('RequestVerificationToken').value);
                                    },

                                    data: dataToSend,

                                    complete: function (result) {

                                        $("#checkExtendDiv").html(result.responseText);
                                        $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                    }
                    $("#addPropertiesPane").show();
                }
            }
        );
}
```

Now the problem is that jQuery is doing well the job and setting properly the parameters. But while performing the query, when the property Modalites on the entity counts 0 elements, the data reaches well the controller. whereas counting at least 1 element, the data reach the controller with null values. Here some print screens of the problem.

[image]

Here a proof that parameters are set properly before Ajax call. Then somehow everything is null after.

[image]

Comment: put index value to list items: <input type="hidden" name="yourListName.index" id="yourListName_index" value="0">

Comment: Actually just before the ajax call, when I debug, all parameters are set correctly which means all lists are set to the object to pass. I went through ajax debug, I noticed some parameter saying cancelled = true

Comment: What about add `[FromBody]` attribute to your action parameter?